# In comparison construction, can 'that' be recovered as in relative clause?

Tags: comparison, relative-clauses

> [i] This is the watch (that) I lost.
>  [ii] This is the same
>   watch **as (that)** I lost.

It is said accusative relative words can be dropped as in [i]. 
CGEL saying there are omissions in adjuncts of comparison, I wonder if there is the omission in [ii] like *that* in [i]. From the following case which I found in COCA, it could be ‘*that*’. Is it? If it is, can ‘*that*’ be recovered and used as is in [i]?

> Following Case:
>  Is it fair to raise the public sector retirement
>   age to the same level **as that** found in the private sector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [i] the deleted *that* is the head of a relative clause; you may choose to regard it either as a relative pronoun or, following CGEL, as a subordinator.

In [ii], however, and in your example, *that* is a demonstrative pronoun = *that one* acting as the object of *as*.  In both cases *that* is modified by a reduced relative clause, with the relative *that/which* already deleted (along with *BE* in your example - 'Whiz-deletion')

> This is the same watch as that <s>which</s> I lost.
>   ... the same level as that <s>which is</s> found in the private sector?

In speech the distinction between relative and demonstrative *that* is even clearer: relative *that* is unstressed and pronounced with a reduced vowel in the neighborhood of /ɛ/, while demonstrative *that* is stressed and produced with /æ/.